# do another job first before handling windows key, 'enter'

Tags: python

I'm searching if it's possible no.2 task. I'm making a sample GUI program in Windows.

1. Python waits till the enter or other keys pressed in Window.
2. When the key is pressed, python runs its own logic first. <<
3. After its own logic is handled, then the key event goes on.

So, this means I want to make Windows key event waited until my logic is done.

Do you guys have an API or a way to recommend?

Comment: pynput can listen for keyboard events even when the window doesnt have focus i think ... (but i dont think you can "intercept" them before the enter event actually fires to whatever had it) ...but the rest of whatever you are trying to do might be harder than you think ...

Comment: Not all keypresses get delivered to your program *at all*. I wouldn't be surprised if the OS not only doesn't let you intercept, but doesn't tell you that context is switching away until it's over.

Comment: Any reason you can't have the Enter key handler do both tasks, one after the other?

Comment: Thank you for answering to all. Actually, it doesn't need to touch Windows key enter. I'm thinking of capturing a screen from browser and it requires enter or other keys. If it's harder, then I need to search to make key event waited before sending it to browser.

Comment: However, it combines multiple keys at the same time. So, I would like to get the keys and control the action if possible. Won't it be easier with c++?